# OpenVPN Gateway Debian - Selective routing howto

Tags: debian, openvpn

My router doesn't support VPN client so i'd like to create a VM on my ESXI with a Debian machine which runs an OpenVPN client and then use that VM as a gateway for my other computers.

I'd like to do selective ip/port forwarding but can't find any tutorial on how to do this (all tutorials are written for asus routers,...)

I tried to do like this :

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x7000 table main prio 100

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.0.2 -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark 0x7000/0x7000
```

The idea was to tell 192.168.0.2 not to use the VPN by connecting the main table but it doesn't work...

Could any one give me help please ? I suck with iptables so please don't be hard on explains.

Thanx !!

Comment: OpenVPN puts its routes in the main table as well, doesn't it?

Comment: so how to put vpn traffic to another table then selective route to this table ?